# Question about my small solar panels

Tags: current, short-circuit, solar-energy, diy

[image]I have some small solar panels and I wanna build a project. My project includes the solar panels and a phone power bank that has input of 2 A. Right now I have the solar panels connected to each other but in a circuit that makes more Volts not Amperes.  So the big white one has on the back a short circuit current.. Does that mean that if I wire the solar panels in a way to give more Amperes not volts and it generates more power than that Short Circuit Current (Lsc) it will be destroyed? By the way I tried charging the power bank (10000 mAh) with them set up to give more volts, it charged for 7 hours and lasted 2 minutes and 28 seconds.

Also I have another question... if lets say I have a product that needs an input of 1 A and lets say I generate more what will happen?

Power bank specifications are 5 V/2 A on everything.

Also I have connected them in series following the guide on this site:

https://www.alternative-energy-tutorials.com/solar-power/connecting-solar-panels-together.html

Comment: Not what you asked, but sounds like you need a MPPT solar charger circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the big white one has on the back a short circuit current.. Does
> that mean that if i wire the solar panels in a way to give more
> Amperes not volts and it generates more power than that Short Circuit
> Current (Lsc) it will be destroyed?

No, the short circuit current specification means the absolute maximum current you can get from that panel when you short-circuit its output, it means nothing more, and the panel will be fine even if you keep it short-circuited.

> ..i tried charging the power bank (10000mAh) with them setted up to
> give more volts, it charged for 7 hours and lasted 2 minutes and 28
> seconds.

Depending on the amount of light hitting the panel(s), you may have had 0.5A or less current out of the panels. Also you didn't include all the details (schematic, diagram, pictures) to give us a full picture of what exactly is going on in your case. It could be 10 different issues with your setup.

> Also i have another question... if let's say i have a product that
> needs an input of 1 ampere and lets say i generate more what will
> happen?

As long as you give it the appropriate voltage, the current you can provide can be exactly what it requires or 1000 times more, the product will only take what it needs, and there should be no problems.